# How do I force standard output on a C# Process when UseShellExecute == false?

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, output, redirectstandardoutput

I am running processes from C# using the following code;

```
private static void ExecuteShellCMD(string workingDir, string commandWithArgs, bool bWait = true)
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.Verb = "runas";
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
    info.Arguments = "/C " + commandWithArgs;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    using (Process myProcess = Process.Start(info))
    {
        if (bWait)
        {
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
        }

        int ExitCode = myProcess.ExitCode;

        //Log exit code here.
    }
}
```

It loads an elevated command window and executes the code/bat file I pass it, but *without* logging anything to the console. This doesn't appear to be consistent on other machines, and has worked in the past on my machine, and I wondered if anyone had any ideas about how I can consistently make this Process just print logs into the command window the process makes.

I can see logs if I set `UseShellExecute = true` but then can't use `Verb` without accepting the elevation prompt which is undesirable.

I have tried looking for solutions around the web, and I am aware that I can redirect the output using other settings. Most of the questions and tutorials on this subject seem to deal with redirecting the ouput to somewhere else but I want to be able to keep track of the progress in the command window itself.

Perhaps I have missed an command line argument or similar?

Comment: Can you do something like `Console.SetIn(myProcess.StandardOutput);`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DavidG, I tried enabling output redirection and adding the line you mentioned. Unfortunately this had the same result. My thinking is that this is a problem with `cmd.exe` itself rather than the process, but I can't think (or find info on) how this can happen. Does anyone know how to invoke a similar process from say Window's 'Run As...' dialogue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was actually a bug in Unity Hub. The process and output were working fine, however when ran from a Unity instance that was launched from Unity Hub it took control of the output and didn't release it. This was solved by just launching Unity directly and a bug report has been filed against Unity hub.